# Good programming practice to include ELSE statements for most IF statements?

Tags: c, if-statement

Consider this pseudocode:

```
while( 1 ){
    if( this happens )
        break;

    if( something else is true )
        do something;
}
```

This code can be translated into the phase: If `this happens` break, otherwise keep going and `do something`. This is essentially equivalent to: If `this happens` break, ELSE `do something`. 
It's easy to see that if `this happens` then we are going to break from the infinite loop, otherwise we are going to execute the remaining code.

However, if we break from the loop then we are obviously not going to be worried if `something else`i s true. So, is it necessarily a good idea to do something like this?

```
while( 1 ){
    if( this happens )
        break;
    else 
        if( something else is true )
            do something;
}
```

Where I could see an ELSE statement being required is with this case:

```
while( 1 ){
    if( !(this happens) ){
        if( something else is true)
            do something;
        }
    else
        break; 
}
```

The readability is improved with the last two versions in my opinion, but all three of these loops are equivalent, right? What are the efficiency differences between these implementations?

Comment: I dont think they are equivalent

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something then. I speak of equality in terms of their effect, not with respect to the generated code.

Comment: In the first example, neither `if()` may be true.  `if (foo1()) break; if (foo2()) do_something();`

Comment: I don't think "readability" is something that all developers assess with the same criteria. Me, I tend to use extra "else" statements; many of my peers hate it. Different strokes.

Comment: The last example requires either braces `{ ... }` or another `else` to avoid having the (single) `else` associate with the inner `if`.

Comment: Perhaps not the best example, as I'd code it like this: `while ( this does not  happen ) {
       

    if ( something else is true )
        do something;
}`

Comment: @alk, of course, but I was just asking a question with regards to the necessity of including non-essential ELSE statements and the associated impact on efficiency.

Comment: In larger code bases with larger cases, the later version become harder to read and harder to modify without making errors.  While the first form seems like a thin veneer over a GOTO, in the circles I've programmed in, it was preferred.

Comment: @chux: sure, but their are both encased in an infinite while loop that is only broken given the condition where the first if() evaluates true. The point of the question is really with respect to the necessity and efficiency of including ELSE statements where they're are not required.

Comment: @woolstar, the first example is the template that I have always used as well. I was just wondering about the consequence of the other formats. Good point about the errors.

Answer (score 4):

> I was just asking a question with regards to the necessity of including non-essential ELSE statements and the associated impact on efficiency.

```
while( 1 ){
    if( this happens )
        break;

    if( something else is true )
        do something;
}
```

or

```
while( 1 ){
    if( this happens )
        break;
    else 
        if( something else is true )
            do something;
}
```

basically, I'd say both are quite equivalent, and if I take strictly my university programing courses, both are as well wrong. But it's not because of whether or not you use the `else`, but because you do an unnecessary condition in the while statement. At every loop, you do test whether `1` is true, which is always the case, then you test with a `if` a condition, so basically the correct form of your example would be:

```
while ( ! (this happens) ) {
    if (something else)
        do something;
}
```

which is way more readable and somehow more efficient (the same way `++i;` is more efficient than `i++;`)

In the end, I guess all forms we're talking about are quite equivalent in term of efficiency because the compiler should easily be able to transform that into the same complexity of assembly, but depending on the context, one may be better than the others for readability.

my 2 cents...

Comment: Someone made the same point in the comments. This short snippet of psuedocode was adapted from a more specific, non-infinite loop application. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: my point is that as long as you can avoid using `break;`, `continue;` `return;` in loops, just avoid them! If you can use a global condition to be tested at every iteration, use it ; if you can use if/else instead of a continue, use that! etc.. But sometimes, you have to break that rule, because you can make "exceptions" or "error handling" spotting out by using `if (this) break;` or `if (that) return xx;`, which that way makes the code more readable, whereas in term of efficiency, it's pretty much the same complexity.

Answer (score 2):

I will expand a little more behind my original comment.  In the thirty years I've been programming, two things have remained almost constant:

- Lines of code a programmer can write in a day
- Number of errors that creep in per lines of code

To that end, using the more compact form is faster to write, and has statistically less bugs.  As I mentioned before, its also less prone to errors when being edited and is easier to reason about.